Deriving subtended angle in QGIS
Is there a tool to calculate the subtended angle between an observer & observed point(s)?
I've searched on "angle" and generally hunted, but not found anything.


The arcsine (inverse of the sine) of the result of (height divided by the distance) will be the angle.

@CaryH that's if the "distance" is the red or blue line length in the diagram. In a 3d "height" context, the subtended angle is the inverse tangent (arctan, or atan) of the height of the tower over the distance to the base of the tower. So a 100m height tower 100m away subtends arctan(100/100) = 45 degrees

Using Spaceman's atan answer I calculated the angle from the tip and from the base and substracted the latter from the former to give the angle - the observer is unlikely to be (looking at a mast in the countryside) viewing as part of a right angled triangle because the mast base could be elevated (eg on top of a hill).
